# What bulb is in the front right turn signal/parking light bulb in a Honda Accord 2003 Sedan?

Tags: honda, headlight, accord, lights, turn-signal

The bulb in my front right turn signal/parking light bulb in my Honda Accord 2003 is out. This is the orange light above the main headlight on the passenger side. I found the instructions for how to change the bulb in my owner's manual, pp. 315-316, but I cannot seem to find what bulb I need to buy. I was hoping to only need to do the process one time, as it appears slightly complex for what it is.

How can I find what the necessary bulb is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, the bulb is a [1157A](http://www.modifiedlife.com/2003-honda-accord-sedan-car-light-bulb-size-chart/). These are *very* standard bulbs and can be picked up most anywhere (Walmart, AutoZone, Checkers, O'Reilly's, etc). The "A" in the identification indicates it as an amber bulb. You can find the 1157 which is the same exact bulb without the amber tint.